# Sendind E-mail on behalf of other user in VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, email

I have a VB.NET application, and I need the application to populate email account of the user's department instead of their personal account. I need to know if its possible to write a simple VB.NET code to do that for me. It's like when the user click on reply button from my application it must just populate that account e.g `finance@hean.co.za` unlike `jeffrey@hean.com`

I'll greatly appreciate your help & I have already try following code:

```
vItem.sendONbehalfName ="finance@hean.co.za"
```

it do populate but deny sending the email.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `sendONbehalfName` method.

Comment: @MattWilko I think `sendONbehalfName` would be a property.

Comment: Better post the complete code.

Comment: Ah this is the 5th question i have encounter today which didn't have enough information. This community can help if there is good information provided.

Comment: You say "it do populate but deny sending the email." so I'll assume your opening a new mail message in outlook or something similar and trying to set the 'From Address' as something else. This will only work if the user has permission to send mail on behalf of that user. So this is probably a mail server issue rather than a problem with your code. But as others have said, there's not enough information here to really help. Guessing sucks.